# Regex to match username using negative look aheads?

Tags: regex

I want to use a regex such that I'm given a list of matches for username where there is not "." present in the name

**Account Name:  sasha.grey** //bad match

**Account Name:  liz.hurley**  //bad match

**Account Name:  sharonstone**  //match

**Tried out regex:**

Account Name:\s+(.*?(?!.))

I have tried this match on Regexbudy and result it doesn't work in both cases.

Comment: Why do you need lookaheads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think vks answer is correct.

Another way (avoiding lookaheads at all) would be to simply match everything but `.` and `\n` (and whatever character should not be in the account name

```
Account Name:\s+([^.\n]+)$
```

Edit: `$` to mark the end of line (oder end of file - depends on flavor). You might want to use `\n` instead.

Maybe you want to know what your expression is doing:

```
\s+(.*?(?!.))
```

is not working because you match

- `\s+` whitespace (one or more occurences)
- `.*?` any character (one or many, but as less as possible)
- `(?!.)` not **any** character but `\n`

  if you wanted to just ignore literal `.`, you have to escape it (so it's `(?!\.)` or `(?![.])`  - but then, it will still not work since the description is: lookahead for a non literal dot. With this, you match `''` with `.*?` in every of your examples

Comment: Thanks but it hasn't worked as I planned since its matching portion of strings which contains . I want to ignore it completely.

Comment: also pls help me understand when ^ is used inside [ ] it means negation otherwise it means starting with right?

Comment: please provide examples

`^` means "start of string" or "start of line" (depends on option in most flavors)
`[^x]` means "not x"

Answer (score 1):

```
Account Name:\s+(?=[^.]*$).+$
```

You can try this with `positive lookahead`

or

```
Account Name:\s+[^.]+$
```

Comment: It sill matches portion of names with . character I want to avoid off completely.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead assertion.

```
Account Name:\s+(?!.*?\.).+
```

or

```
Account Name:\s+\w+$
```